# Why is IE ignoring cell's widths when a collspan is involved?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Consider this (snipped) example

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">>
<body>
    <table style="background-color: Navy; width:400px">
        <tr>
            <td style="background-color: Green; width:35px">test</td>
            <td style="background-color: Green; width:35px">test</td>
            <td style="background-color: Green; width:35px">t</td>
            <td style="background-color: Green">buffer</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                <img src="http://www.tiepvoud.nl/archief/boris_jeltsin.jpg" alt="Product Mixing Gauges" width="400" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

This is working fine in all browsers but IE.
If the image is small enough (say 40) all is well. When the size of the image is a bit bigger (say 200) IE starts wonking up the cell widths.
What's happening?

**--SIDENOTE--**
To the people suggesting to use CSS. I know. It's an abstracted example.
Tables are still valid HTML and shouldn't be feared. Tabular data is supposed to be in tables. Re-inventing tables with divs is at least as blasfemous as creating a table based lay-out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you hardcode the width of the 4th column it works as expected...

> ```
> ...
> <td style="background-color: Green; width:295px">buffer</td>
> ...
> ```

It ignores the colspan attribute, so if the image's width is more thant the first column it mixes all up. Search for "[IE6 colspan bug](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&lr=&ie=UTF-8&q=IE+6+colspan+bug&btnG=Search)"...

---

[EDIT:]
If you have to do it with tables, that (not beautiful) might work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">>
<body>
    <table style="background-color: Navy; width:400px">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <table width="100%">
              <tr>
                <td style="background-color: Green; width:35px">test</td>
                <td style="background-color: Green; width:35px">test</td>
                <td style="background-color: Green; width:35px">t</td>
                <td style="background-color: Green">buffer</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4">
            <img src="http://www.tiepvoud.nl/archief/boris_jeltsin.jpg" alt="Product Mixing Gauges" width="400" />
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Reminds me a little of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469445/last-words-of-a-programmer/470462#470462)

But I really think you **should use CSS** for layout!!!

Comment: Indeed. Great, now I have to put width calculation in my page since the number columns is variable :S Therefore I can't put the styling in my CSS! God I hate IE!

Comment: Voted for good comment because of the "God..." If IE wouldn't be there, design time of a web site would be about a 3rd I think...

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<style type="text/css">table {table-layout: fixed;}</style>
```

It should works, this occur only in IE6 i guess (not with IE7 & IE8)

or you can use width:auto in your 4th column

```
<td style="background-color: Green; width: auto;">buffer</td>
```

Btw i hope you didn't use the above code to create a table based layout (which was old fashion, hey you should learn CSS based layout this day)

Comment: it's an abstracted example ;) I know what css is all about.

Answer (score 0):

what DOCTYPE if any are you specifying above your `<html>` tag

Does it work if you change it to

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
```

OR

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
```

Comment: In this abstracted example I have none. In my real code it is XHTML 1.0 strict. Changing it doesn't help. I'll update the OP to reflect my doctype.

Comment: bizarre. just tried it there and the colspan in the second row seems to be breaking it... Seems to be a known issue. http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t158704-ie-screws-up-table-cell-widths-when-colspan-is-used.html

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the **overflow** CSS property on a few things, like maybe the table

eg: `<table style="background-color: Navy; width:400px;**overflow: hidden**">`

Answer (score 0):

There is a CSS based grid system called [960](http://960.gs/) that is easy to learn, and will work for IE, FF and Sarari.  It will help enforce the column spans you have defined and creates cleaner mark up.  Here is a nice [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/prototyping-with-the-grid-960-css-framework/).

I was skeptical at first, as I am an old ASP.NET guy but it has saved me a ton of time with maintenance and cross browser issues.  I also found that by using tables less, I could incorporate more client side functionality more rapidly.  That's a definite plus.

Comment: I don't like css grid layouts for several reasons. The most important one being the fact that defining your with in a classname is the same as putting a hardcoded width value.